Which theorems are known about this geometric construction?
I'm looking to get more insight on geometric construction of this kind. Given a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ and two midpoints $M$ and $N$, as on this drawing:

Is there a known theorem about angles between segments $AN$ and $BM$?
I know that if $ABCD$ is a square, these two segments are perpendicular.
I would also like to find out some theorems about the quadrilateral $PQRS$ if I connect all vertices of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ with midpoints of opposite sides.


So this depends on which opposite side to connect. Connect $AK$, $BN$, $CM$, $DL$, then the quadrilateral formed might be different.

If you're interested, there are worthwhile calculations to be done with areas in these diagrams. Bringing angles in is less likely to give us something natural, since the setup doesn't tell us anything about angles.

@peterwhy What is the proper way to refer, say, to the side $CD$ with respect to vertex $A$?

@MishaLavrov I'm very interested to know about these areas!
